# Oracle SQL: Change an already-existing relationship from mandatory to optional

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a foreign key named `my_fk` that goes between two tables named `table_a` and `table_b`, where `table_a` is the "many" side and `table_b` contains the unique record that `table_a` is referencing.  How would I go about changing an already-existing relationship from mandatory to optional?  What SQL do I need to type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle optional relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190446/oracle-optional-relationship)

Comment: @attilacsipak This is in not a duplicate -- read the title or the question.  What is it with the SO community and being sick with power?!?  _Already-existing_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the relationship optional, you just need to allow nulls in the column from `table_a` that has a foreign key relationship to the `table_b` table.

```
alter table table_a modify fk_col_name null
```

Note: Replace `fk_col_name` by the actual column name.